# reply to thread google-api-ruby-client

Tags: ruby, gmail, gmail-api

So here's what my code (pretty much) looks like to create a message using the google-api-ruby-client:

```
  service ||= Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new

  message = RMail::Message.new
  message.header['To'] = params[:gmail][:to]
  message.header['From'] = current_user_google_user_id
  message.header['Subject'] = params[:gmail][:subject]
  message.header['Subject'] = params[:gmail][:subject]
  message.body = params[:gmail][:body]

  service.send_user_message(
    current_user_google_user_id,
    upload_source: StringIO.new(message.to_s),
    content_type: 'message/rfc822',
    thread_id: params[:gmail][:thread_id]
  )
```

It obviously fails because of where I have `thread_id`. If I remove that line, things work fine, but I'm not able to keep things scoped to a thread. How should I be passing the thread ID to the GmailService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source on GitHub for [`send_user_message`](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/e3b8c800d649da00748d4605d847b342480ecc73/generated/google/apis/gmail_v1/service.rb#L1150) shows that it doesn't take a `thread_id` as a parameter. However the [`Message` class](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/e3b8c800d649da00748d4605d847b342480ecc73/generated/google/apis/gmail_v1/classes.rb#L838) does have it as an attribute.

So perhaps trying this should work:

```
  service ||= Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new

  message = RMail::Message.new
  message.header['To'] = params[:gmail][:to]
  message.header['From'] = current_user_google_user_id
  message.header['Subject'] = params[:gmail][:subject]
  message.header['Subject'] = params[:gmail][:subject]
  message.body = params[:gmail][:body]
  message.thread_id = params[:gmail][:thread_id]

  service.send_user_message(
    current_user_google_user_id,
    upload_source: StringIO.new(message.to_s),
    content_type: 'message/rfc822'
  )
```

Comment: I've since changed over to a different gem, but this is essentially what I figured out.

Comment: how to reply but using Mail:Message object ? i can't add thread_id parameter in my Mail:Message object