# How to reply gmail using Gmail API in the same thread_id

Tags: ruby, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

Hi guys currently i'm building reply message using ruby, here is my code

```
    def reply(user_id, subject, to, body, thread_id)
        client = google_client user_id
        token = Token.find_by_user_id(user_id)
        access_token = token.access_token
        gmail = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
        gmail.authorization = client
        message              = Mail.new
        message.date         = Time.now
        message.subject      = "#{subject}"
        message.from         = token.email
        message.to           = "#{to}"
        message.thread_id    = "#{thread_id}"

        message.part content_type: 'multipart/alternative' do |part|
            part.html_part = Mail::Part.new(body: "#{body}", content_type: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')
        end

        # attach file
         open('/Users/jaisanasrulloh/Downloads/image.png') do |file| 
            message.attachments['image.jpg'] = file.read 
         end

        msg = message.encoded
        message_object = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(raw:message.to_s)
        gmail.send_user_message('me', message_object)
    end
```

but i got error like below:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `thread_id=' for #<Mail::Message:0x007fcedb6b9c78>
```

My question is how to add `thread_id` inside `Mail::Message` object ? Some person using class `RMail::Message` like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329035/reply-to-thread-google-api-ruby-client)

is there exist parameter thread_id inside `Mail::Message` ? if there exist how to add it?

Comment: Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads#adding_drafts_and_messages_to_threads) to help you further. It was stated that `If you are sending or migrating messages that are a response to another email or part of a conversation, your application should add that message to the related thread. This makes it easier for Gmail users who are participating in the conversation to keep the message in context.`

Comment: yes i know that can give you detail example may be ?

Answer (score 1):

thread_id is a part of the Gmail message object not the Mail object.

Add it here

```
message_object = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(raw:message.to_s, thread_id:thread_id)
```

and remove this:

```
message.thread_id    = "#{thread_id}"
```